# Is there an option for 2 seconds after hitting the submit button display an alert and then complete the form request?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the code

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" novalidate="">
<input type="text" id="NameInput" name="NameInput">
<button type="submit">Complete</button>
</form>
```

I want to show an alert like "The form has been submited!" and after clicking submit the form and complete the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener for the `submit` event that prevents the form from submitting by calling `Event.preventDefault()`, then use `setTimeout` to execute a function which alerts and submits the form programmatically after 2000 milliseconds:

```js
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("The form has been submited!")
    myForm.submit();
  }, 2000)
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="POST" novalidate="">
  <input type="text" id="NameInput" name="NameInput">
  <button type="submit">Complete</button>
</form>
```